# targeting css class under specific div only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-1-box">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

how can I use target glyphicon glyphicon-ok under this `col-sm-1 col-1-box` class only?

I tried with

```
.col-1-box + .glyphicon .glyphicon-ok {     
  ...
}
```

but that doesnt work, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: remove `+`     ...............

Answer (score 1):

You also can Try:

```
  .col-1-box > .glyphicon.glyphicon-ok {     
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

It's the direct child, not a recursive match.

Answer (score 1):

'+' is for next sibling and space is for all child elements

As your HTML like this

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-1-box">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</div>
```

then CSS

```
.col-1-box .glyphicon.glyphicon-ok {     
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove space between `.glyphicon` and `.glyphicon-ok`

```css
.col-1-box + .glyphicon.glyphicon-ok {     
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1 col-1-box"></div>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">Lorem Ipsum</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  .col-sm-1.col-1-box .glyphicon.glyphicon-ok{.....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this might be this will help

```css
.col-sm-1 span.glyphicon{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-1 col-1-box">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

you can see color of ok icon is black and i change it to red

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` for direct child:

```
.col-sm-1.col-1-box > .glyphicon.glyphicon-ok {  ...  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the HTML inside a span that has a unique id or class name.

```
<span class="awwwwyeah">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-1-box">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </div> <!-- I assume the div ends somewhere -->
</span>
```

Then you can access the elements with css

```
.awwwwyeah .col-1-box .glyphicon-ok{
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The **element+element** selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element. Quoting it directly from the w3schooldoc.

For more details read [element + element selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) here.

Let's see an example

```css
.parentElement .childElement {
   /*Selected Children only*/
   background: red;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .notImmediate {
   background: blue;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
 }
.childElement + .childElement {
  /*Selected immediately after (not inside) */
   border-right: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentElement">
  <div class="childElement">
    <div class="notImmediate"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="childElement"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusing! Here are the two possible scenarios - Choose as per your requirement

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}
/* scenario 1 */

.col-1-box + .glyphicon.glyphicon-ok {
  color: tomato;
}
/* scenario 2 */

.col-1-box .glyphicon.glyphicon-ok {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<h1>Scenario 1</h1>
<div class="col-sm-1 col-1-box"></div>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">OK</span>

<hr>
<h1>Scenario 2</h1>
<div class="col-sm-1 col-1-box">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">OK</span>
</div>
```